# no data is passed into state when using useContext/useReducer together with useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

```
export const itemReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, createContext, useContext } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { CURRENT_MONTH_BY_USER } from '../graphql/queries'
import { itemReducer } from '../reducers/ItemReducer'

const Items = createContext()

export const ItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let items = []
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(itemReducer, { items: items })

  const result = useQuery(CURRENT_MONTH_BY_USER)
  if (result.data && result.data.getCurrentMonthByUser) {
    items = [...result.data.getCurrentMonthByUser]
  }

  return <Items.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Items.Provider>
}

export const ItemsState = () => {
  return useContext(Items)
}

export default ItemProvider
```

`let items` gets correct data from the **useQuery**, however nothing is passed into the state, therefore I am unable to transfer data into another components from the context. What am I doing wrong here?

When debugging both `items` and `state` they're initially empty because of the loading however then only the `items` receives correct data and state remains as empty array.

If i put static data into `let items` it works just fine, so maybe there can be something wrong with my **useQuery** as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to see your problem if you look at where `items` is used. That's only as the initial state to your `useReducer` call - but `items` is only set to a non-empty value *after* this. That has absolutely no effect on the component, because `items` is not used later in your component function, and the initial state is only ever set once, on the first render.

To solve this you need to embrace your use of a reducer, adding a new action type to set this initial data, and then dispatching that when you have the data. So add something like this to your reducer:

```
export const itemReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INITIAL_DATA: // only a suggestion for the name, and obviously you need to define this as a constant
      return { ...state, items: action.items };
    /* other actions here */
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and then rewrite your component like this:

```
export const ItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(itemReducer, { items: [] })

  const result = useQuery(CURRENT_MONTH_BY_USER)
  if (result.data && result.data.getCurrentMonthByUser) {
    dispatch({ type: SET_INITIAL_DATA, items: result.data.getCurrentMonthByUser });
  }

  return <Items.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Items.Provider>
}
```

Also, while this is unrelated to your question, I will note that your `ItemsState` export appears to be a custom hook (it can't be anything else since it isn't a component but uses a hook) - that is perfectly fine but there is a very strong convention in React that all custom hooks have names of the form `useXXX`, which I strongly suggest you should follow. So you could rename this something like `useItemsState` (I would prefer `useItemsContext` to make clear it's just a `useContext` hook specialised to your specific context).